# How to prevent duplicate records from being inserted on the same day in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I'm confused on how to approach this. I have a table that I created that I am inserting data into every day at a fixed time. I want to make sure there are no duplicate records inserted on the same day. Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_daily_records`()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table1 (
    `Insertion Date`, 
    `Last Updated`,
    `Account Number`,
    ) 
    SELECT 
    curdate(),
    NULL,
    `Account Number`,
    FROM view1;
END
```

`Insertion date` has the value of the current date whenever the script is ran so for example, it would be `2022-12-08`. `Last Updated` is the timestamp of the most recent time the script is ran so it would read `2022-12-08 17:53:56.000` for example. So if the script is ran today it would look like this after 1 run:

```
Insertion Date Last Updated              Account Number

2022-12-08    2022-12-08 17:53:56.000   9332
2022-12-08    2022-12-08 17:53:56.000   0992
2022-12-08    2022-12-08 17:53:56.000   5424
2022-12-08    2022-12-08 17:53:56.000   4910
```

The problem is, if the script runs again in the same day, it would show duplicate records like this:

```
Insertion Date Last Updated              Account Number

2022-12-08    2022-12-08 17:53:56.000   9332
2022-12-08    2022-12-08 17:53:56.000   0992
2022-12-08    2022-12-08 17:53:56.000   5424
2022-12-08    2022-12-08 17:53:56.000   4910
2022-12-08    2022-12-08 21:55:30.000   9332
2022-12-08    2022-12-08 21:55:30.000   0992
2022-12-08    2022-12-08 21:55:30.000   5424
2022-12-08    2022-12-08 21:55:30.000   4910
```

The second run, which are the bottom 4 records that got appended, are the same as the initial run except for the last updated field which shows a different time. The date and the account number are the same. I know the records technically aren't duplicates, but I don't want the same records to be inserted twice even though it shows a different updated time. Is there any way to prevent duplicates from being inserted into the target table?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add a `UNIQUE` constraint to your combination of all fields as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE tab
ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE(`Insertion Date`, `Last Updated`, `Account Number`);
```

This will have the side effect of firing you an error when the procedure is unable of adding an already-existing row, still preventing the new rows to be added.

If having errors doesn't work for you, using the [`IGNORE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) keyword right after the `INSERT` keyword will make the non-insertion of the row silent. Although it may work for you, silencing errors is never recommended.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_daily_records`()
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (
    `Insertion Date`, 
    `Last Updated`,
    `Account Number`,
    ) 
    SELECT 
    curdate(),
    NULL,
    `Account Number`,
    FROM view1;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dWcVjmXG5e7qqsE8VHDiXm/0).

---

If you want to avoid silencing the DBMS errors, yet another option is to use the [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) statement in place of the `INSERT` statement. This will act as an `INSERT` if it doesn't find any duplicate, otherwise will delete the existing duplicate row and insert the new one.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_daily_records`()
BEGIN
    REPLACE INTO table1 (
    `Insertion Date`, 
    `Last Updated`,
    `Account Number`,
    ) 
    SELECT 
    curdate(),
    NULL,
    `Account Number`,
    FROM view1;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

The drawback of this solution is on efficiency, as it will always apply a deletion and an insertion whenever a duplicate row is found.

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dWcVjmXG5e7qqsE8VHDiXm/1).

Comment: i dont think adding a unique constraint would work because im going to have multiple records with the same date, but the records are going to be different. if i add a unique constraint then every record has to be different for the date column

Comment: You'll get unique values for combinations of all your fields - in this case triplets of (InsertionDate + LastUpdated + AccountNumber), otherwise said, avoiding full record duplicates. You'll still be able to add same InsertionDate for different AccountNumber values.